# jinternalframe in a jframe

Tags: java

closing a `jframe` and simultaneously opening another `jframe`(1) with a button is easy
we can do this by `close(), dispose,this.setvisibe(false)`

my query is :-
i have made a `jinternalframe` in a `jframe` which i implemented using jdesktopPane
i have a button LOGIN in the `jinternalframe` which closes the `jinternalframe` only(and not the `jframe` in which the internal frame resides) and opens another `jframe`(1).
i want a code which will close `jframe`(which has the internalframe) on clicking the button LOGIN in `jinternalframe`

Comment: If you provide code of what you are doing, you'll more than likely receive an answer quicker and with example code on how to do what you are asking.

Comment: You've already been told that a) you need a reference to the JFrame, that b) you can get this from SwingUtilities, and that c) this application behavior is to be frowned upon. Why aren't you listening to this advice given in  your cross-post? And why are you not telling folks about your other cross-posts?

Comment: One cross-post of several: [jinternal-frame-jfram-query](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/59279-jinternal-frame-jfram-query.html)